# Room - saving complex object in Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I've a TestData class like this:

```
data class TestData(
    @TypeConverters(TestDataConverter::class)
    var peripheral: BluetoothPeripheral,
    var isEnabled: Boolean
)
```

As I understand, to save objects that are not primitive, I've to use Coverter. I created it like this:

```
class TestDataConverter {
    companion object {
        var gson = Gson()

        @TypeConverter
        @JvmStatic
        fun fromJson(json: String): BluetoothPeripheral {
            val type = object : TypeToken<BluetoothPeripheral>() {}.type
            return gson.fromJson(json, type)
        }

        @TypeConverter
        @JvmStatic
        fun toJson(peripheral: BluetoothPeripheral): String {
            val type = object: TypeToken<BluetoothPeripheral>() {}.type
            return gson.toJson(torrent, type)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:704)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:683)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:638)
        at c.room.TestDataConverter$Companion.toJson(TestDataConverter.kt:23)
        at c.room.TestDataConverter.toJson(Unknown Source:2)
```

How to successfully store this type of complex object? Is it possible?

Comment: What i did is saving response in string format and converting to Json when need to use.

Comment: @KaushikBurkule Can u show me sample code, please?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should use a static class object of a class with companion. When I first tried Room. I had the same question. Ether you can add @TypeConverters to your entity instead of a field.

```
@TypeConverter
object BluetoothPeripheral TypeConverter {
  @JvmStatic
  fun toJson(): String? { ... }

  @JvmStatic
  fun fromJson(): BluetoothPeripheral { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the whole point in using converters is to represent our data in primitive type since SQLite support only a few types. Here you are trying to convert an object into String/TEXT. The converter logic is correct but the class *BluetoothPeripheral* may contain (I'm not sure since you don't provide the definition) nested objects, hence the converter don't know how to convert them into a string.